# How to embed longer code examples into a presentation?

Tags: presentations, source-code

I am going to hold a company presentation about a software development and programming topic, where beside the normal textual and graphical data, several source code examples should be embedded in the presentation. The problem which I face is that some of these code examples are a bit too long to fit on a single screen or slide and I would like to find a proper presentation style and format which can deal with this issue.

I considered the following things:

- The code examples serve demonstration purposes and will be thoroughly analysed and explained, therefore it is not an option to just reference them and make them available for the audience to check them out later if they would like.
- The examples are quite numerous, so opening the code samples in a code editor and switching back and forth between the presentation and the code editor application would be quite interfering I think.
- The classical "slide after slide" presentation style cannot contain longer examples on a single slide and since scrolling are not supported in most of them, I would have to break these samples into multiple slides - also does not sound really good to me.

My question is that what presentation style or tool would you advise when longer code samples must be embedded in a presentation?

The best idea I have came up with so far is to create a single-paged website, which I can open in any browser in full screen mode as the presentation. In this format I could freely embed normal textual and graphical data and also code examples. Scrolling for longer code sections would be supported, therefore they would not be required to be broken into parts. (I could even place "run this example" buttons in the presentation, which would link to fiddles, so if I make the presentation available online, it would be really easy for the audience to experiment with the given samples.)

Any other ideas or suggestions and experiences for such cases?